# Why putting <T> after class name?

Tags: c#

What's the using of class `<TClass>` after class name. For example

```
public class Foo<TFooSomething,string> where TFooSomething :class {

    public Foo(IBoo<TBooSomething> boo) : base(boo)
    {
       //code goes here
    }
}
```

If it's just for declaring parameter types, can't we just declare them in the constructor?

Comment: Look up "generics in c#"

Comment: Try to write your implementation of LINQ `Select` without generics and use it, and it will become clear :)

Comment: Btw.: a class-name must not be followed by curly braces `()`, that won´t even compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a generic type, very useful in classes where the content can be of different types. A good example is List, where T specifies what types the elements in the list belong to. Sure, you can use non-generic types such as ArrayList, but that means that when you access an element in the list, you won't know its type. You could of course create a non-generic list-type that takes the element type as a parameter to the constructor, but that just means type-checking needs to be done at run-time instead of relying on C#'s type checking.